# How to clean an image's text before reading with tesseract?

Tags: java, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract to read text from an image. As my BinaryImage input would not be a simple text over a plain white background, I am getting only 50 % as a correct output.

is there any way to preprocess an image so that I can get proper output from tesseract? I have already tried grey scaling and binarizing the image using [Otsu's method](https://bostjan-cigan.com/java-image-binarization-using-otsus-algorithm/),  but there was no improvement.

As I am doing all this using java, it would be helpful if someone can share details of any java lib or steps to get the better results from tesseract.

I am not getting proper ImageMagick docs to use it in my Java code as well. Any help on this is appreciated.

[sample image ( any wireless bill of AT & T)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiYaZ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to optimize my output by grey scaling and binarizing the image, but it wasn't helpful. Then I tried [boofcv](http://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) to sharpen my image and I got 90% optimized output.

before sharpening the image, we can rescale the image if the resolutions are not big enough, using below code:

```
public static BufferedImage scale(BufferedImage img, int imageType, int dWidth, int dHeight, double fWidth, double fHeight) {
BufferedImage img = null;
if(img != null) {
    img = new BufferedImage(dWidth, dHeight, imageType);
    Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(fWidth, fHeight);
    g.drawRenderedImage(img, at);
}
return img;
```

}

in case, anyone gets stuck in same situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your scan of your bill may be at too small a resolution. I believe your would get better results if you had a higher resolution image (bigger dimensions). Also you could try saving your scan in a non-lossy-compressed format. You could try local area thresholding. But I do not think this will help with such small text. Nevertheless, in ImageMagick you could do that with -lat command.

```
convert image.jpg -negate -lat 25x25+10% -negate result.png
```

[image]

Adjust values as desired. I also have a bash unix shell script, textcleaner, that might be be better on other images. You can see examples at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/index.php

Comment: Thanks for helping. I found out very well written java library for image processing. I am able to optimize the output now. I'll be explaining more in my answer.